# Type field in Boolean Wrapper Class?

Tags: java, boolean

In java API documentation, it is written that Boolean wrapper class have **3** fields. True, False and **Type**.
For Type they have given description that:

> **TYPE: The Class object representing the primitive type boolean.**

I can't understand what is this "type" field for?

Comment: it is actually Class<Boolean>

Comment: @SyedaNaqvi Would you like to accept an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Java class is represented in a running Java program by an object of type `java.lang.Class`, which, amongst other things, lets you perform reflective operations upon objects of that type. You can normally get to an object's `Class` by calling `obj.getClass()`, or by specifying its name explicitly, eg. `String.class`.

Primitive types, like `int` and `boolean`, don't have a class to represent them. But there are situations where it would be appropriate to have a `Class` object for them, and the `TYPE` members of the wrapper class types (like `java.lang.Integer` and `java.lang.Double`) represent exactly these `Class` objects.

You might be given one if you perform reflective operations on, say, an array of booleans, like this:

```
    boolean[] bools = new boolean[1];
    Class<?> c = bools.getClass().getComponentType();
    Assert.assertEquals(Boolean.TYPE, c);  // passes!
```

Note that the *primitive* boolean class is NOT the same as the Boolean wrapper class! That is,

```
    Assert.assertNotSame(Boolean.TYPE, Boolean.class);  // passes!
```

Answer (score 0):

`TYPE` is a `Class<Boolean>` compile-time constant of the `Boolean` wrapper class representing the primitive type (`boolean`) the `Boolean` class wraps around.

The same is in all object wrappers: they all have a `TYPE` constant representing their primitive counterpart (e.g. [Integer.TYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE)).

Answer (score 0):

It is used in the reflection API, to represent the type of a boolean argument or return type of a method, or the type of a field of a class.